# libvirt nwfilter, multiple parameters

Tags: libvirt, parameter, netfilter

It's possible to pass multiple parameters to the "filterref" using "parameter" keyword. Like this:

```
<filterref filter='no-ip-spoofing'>
   <parameter name='IP' value='10.0.0.1'/>
   <parameter name='IP' value='10.0.0.2'/>
</filterref>
```

And use they in "no-ip-spoofing" inside "rule" statement:

```
<rule action='return' direction='out' priority='500'>
  <ip srcipaddr='$IP'/>
</rule>
```

Each IP (10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2) inside "rule" statement will be processed independently.

**Q: But is it possible to pass parameters as a complex structure?**
For example I want to send to "no-ip-spoofing" not only the IP but also the MASK. Something like that (of course the next list is incorrect xml structure):

```
<filterref filter='no-ip-spoofing'>
   <parameter name='IP' value='10.0.0.1', name='MASK' value='255.255.255.0'/>
   <parameter name='IP' value='10.0.0.2', name='MASK' value='255.255.255.0'/>
</filterref>
```

And process they like that:

```
<rule action='return' direction='out' priority='500'>
  <ip srcipaddr='$IP' srcipmask='$MASK'/>
</rule>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't take it as RTFM, yet documentation has just the thing for such uses (https://libvirt.org/formatnwfilter.html#usage-of-variables-in-filters). Using two arrays of parameters and a single iterator should suffice, and I quote:

```
Accessing the same variables using a single iterator, for example by
using the notation $SRCIPADDRESSES[@1] and $DSTPORTS[@1], would result
in parallel access to both lists and result in the following combinations:
```

<s>Yet I can't tell how to provide such parameters as I am still hitting my head over passing parameters to filters. Comments on that topic would be appreciated.</s>

Side note: In the same chapter it is shown one can get a matrix of parameters with a separate iterator for each.

**Edit:**
One needs to provide the array of arguments as streams as shown at the questions top. For two arrays, just provide two seperate streams:

```
<filterref filter='no-ip-spoofing'>
   <!-- Array of IP values -->
   <parameter name='IP' value='10.0.0.1'/>
   <parameter name='IP' value='10.0.0.2'/>
   <!-- Array of MASK values -->
   <parameter name='MASK' value='255.255.255.0'/>
   <parameter name='MASK' value='255.255.255.0'/>
</filterref>
```

Now, must change the rule as such to iterate in parallel (single loop):

```
<rule action='return' direction='out' priority='500'>
  <ip srcipaddr='$IP[@1]' srcipmask='$MASK[@1]'/>
</rule>
```

[Self promotion] I have put up a somewhat related introductory tutorial regarding nwfilters: https://blog.cbugk.com/post/kvm-guest-network-isolation/